# MongoDB PHP Search giving different results to Mongo Console

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

When I search my mongodb from the mongo console, it works great. Like so:

```
db.collection.runCommand("text", {search: "myterm"})
```

However, when I perform the same search using the PHP mongodb driver, I often get less results:

```
$r = $d->command(array("text" => "collection", 'search' => "myterm" ));
print_r($r);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: How many results each one is returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apolegies, my mistake.

I was excluding the first row thinking they were headers in php, when in fact they were not.